# How to add each item of an array into separate HTML elements using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I looked and did not find another question asking this for jQuery.  If there is please point me to it.

This is my function:

```
function PopAnswers(aelement, adata) {
    var answerCount = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < adata.length; i++) {
        $("aelement" + answerCount).text(adata[i]);
            answerCount++;
    };
}
```

My question object:

```
var question1 = new QuestionBlock(
    "What is the correct jQuery code to set the background color of all p elements to red?",
    [
    '$("p").manipulate("background-color","red");',
    '$("p").style("background-color","red");',
    '$("p").css("background-color","red");',
    '$("p").layout("background-color","red");'
    ],
    2);
```

The call:

```
$("#progressbar h1").click(function() {     
            PopAnswers("#answer", question1.answers);       
    });
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div id="answerbox">
                <div class="answer" id="answer1">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="answer" id="answer2">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="answer" id="answer3">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="answer" id="answer4">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am trying to populate each #answer element with the elements of the array.
Can I get some help, hopefully with a good explanation so I can understand and not have to look this question up again?
Thnaks

Comment: You need to drop double quotes in 4th line of PopAnswers : ` $(aelement + answerCount).text(adata[i]);` because aelement is the variable name here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referencing a non-existing element in your jQuery selector

change this:

```
$("aelement" + answerCount).text(adata[i]); // will try to fetch aelement1
```

into this:

```
$(aelement + answerCount).text(adata[i]); // will try to fetch #answer1
```

Comment: now i feel stupid.  i knew i was close though! Checkmark in 2 minutes.
Thanks